# Programatic Strategy issue about Interstitials ads to earn fast in Android

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I have put Interstitial ad on buttonclick. It will increase probability of clicking.But i want if user try to click cross button (to close ad) instead of clicking ad(in case he do not like ad), the ad clicked automatically and help adding points to my AdMob account.

If there is other strategy please suggest.
Thanks

Here is the code:

```
   // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}
public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Such behaviour will earn you a ban from the advertiser, which will negatively affect the points in your AdMob account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cheating a 3rd party service provider, and not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

From the AdMob publisher guidelines and policies:

Invalid clicks and impressions

Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods. Testing your own ads by clicking on them is not allowed.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?rd=1